# Python Basemap Color Scale in Plot and Colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, colorbar

I'm using `Python Basemap` trying to plot Sea Surface Temperature over a range of years and enforce a constant `contourf` and `colorbar` color scale (and colorbar ticks/labels) over all the plots. These lines of code (for example, i've tried many options) however do not work:

```
cmin = 288          
cmax = 293      
cb_step =0.5            
cb_ticks = np.arange(np.round(cmin),np.round(cmax)+2*cb_step,cb_step)

cvec = cb_ticks
numContours=len(cb_ticks)

ctf=m.contourf(lons2,lats2,vals,numContours*3,cmap=colmap,vmax=cmax,vmin=cmin,latlon=True)

cbar = m.colorbar(ctf, ticks=cb_ticks)
cbar.set_clim(cmin, cmax)
```

I've tried every trick i could find on StackOverflow but the thing does not behave as i'd expect. As the data values are changing with the years, so are the limits and ticks in the colorbar. 
[image]
[image]

Can anyone please point out what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: How did you get your `lons2, lats2, vals` ?  Are they OK ? Can you post a link to your data file ?

Comment: Well, the plots make sense and are properly geo-referenced. I never doubted the values themselves...Anyway, here's a NetCDF with some values:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Yrcg-3fgdwZPtSlYGmTj2d9e1KO_AYNt

Comment: To whom it may concern: one of the issues is a call to `np.round(cmin)` which return nearest integer - which can be pretty far off! `np.round(cmin,1)` rounds to first decimal and is a much better choice!

Comment: That's weird, `vmin` and `vmax` in `contourf` and `ticks` in `colorbar` together should do the trick. Can you post the *entire* code that you used to generate the two images?